# Proxy server message - enable cookies - Selenium/python/scraping

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, web-scraping

I have been trying to access a password protected webpage to view academic articles and carry out a meta-analyses. I would like to point out that I have access to this service, but would like an automated bot to obtain abstracts, given a set of keywords.

1) I tried accessing the page using Chrome 
2) I tried accessing the page in Incognito mode as well.

Both situations, I get this error as soon as I click submit.

```
Please note: In order to use this proxy server, you will need to enable cookies in your web browser.
```

Any suggestions on by-passing this error? Partial Code below:

```
executable_path = "C:\\Users\\rameshv\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path, 
chrome_options=chrome_options)

browser.get("https://login.proxy-remote.galib.uga.edu/login") 
#time.sleep(15)

username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]/form/input[2]")
username.send_keys('')

password = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]/form/input[3]")
password.send_keys('')

browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[1]/form/input[5]").click()
```

I get the proxy error as soon as I hit the submit button.

Comment: Can you share the code written so far ?

Comment: Added code above @aberna

Comment: Cannot replicate your issue. I used your code and tried to access to login with Chrome (not incognito) and after clicking submit I received the message "Invalid Login. Please check your credentials and try again." which seems quite fair.

Comment: Providing the username and password for a wee bit. Please take a look as soon as possible @aberna

Comment: Got it and tested. Are you sure the service it is correctly working ? I tried to access it in a normal browser and access it is denied for cookies issue. But they are on.

Comment: That's really weird.:/